# Can we solve this limit without squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I was wondering if we can solve this limit without using squeeze (sandwich) theorem.
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}(3^n+5^n)^{2/n}$$

Comment: Use the fact that $3^n\ll5^n$.

Comment: @Shrey what exactly are you looking for ? The first principle needs $|(3^n+5^n)^{2/n} - 25|$ to be *squeezed* to $0$ ;)

Comment: Why would you want to?  All of the below proofs seem more complicated and less direct than the observation $5^n \leq 3^n + 5^n \leq (2)5^n$.

Comment: Thank you all for responding. I got what I was looking for in solutions below. I started doing this using l'Hospital's but got stuck. Although applying squeeze theorem is easier but it doesn't hurt to know alternative solution.

Comment: Yep.  Just post it on math.SE. . . oh I get it now.

Comment: @Shrey: Yes it is interesting to see alternative solutions, but you should also remember that most limit theorems are proven by using the squeeze theorem or some equivalent at some point. And many times hard bounds tell you much more than just the limit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Certainly.
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty} \exp\left(\ln\left((3^n + 5^n)^{2/n}\right)\right) = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \exp \left(\frac{2\ln(3^n + 5^n)}{n}\right) = \exp\left(\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{2\ln(3^n + 5^n)}{n}\right)
$$

Now, let's solve $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{2\ln(3^n + 5^n)}{n}$. We have $\displaystyle \frac{+\infty}{+\infty}$, so we can apply l'Hospital's rule straight away, giving us:
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{2 \ln(3) 3^n + 2 \ln(5) 5^n}{3^n + 5^n} = 2 \ln(5)
$$

So, the limit is $\displaystyle \exp(2 \ln(5)) = 25$.

Answer (score 6):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x) =  e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\ln(f(x))}}=e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac2n\ln(3^n+5^n)}}=e^{2\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{\ln{3^n+5^n}}{n}}}$$

Now let's use a L'Hopital's rule:

$$e^{2\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{\ln{3^n+5^n}}{n}}}=e^{2\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{3^n\ln3+5^n\ln5}{3^n+5^n}}}=e^{2\lim_{n \to \infty}{\ln5+\frac{3^n\ln3-3^n\ln5}{3^n+5^n}}}=e^{2\ln5}=e^{\ln25}=25$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to \infty}(3^n+5^n)^{2/n}\\
=&\lim_{n\to \infty}\exp\left( {2\log(3^n+5^n)/n}\right)\\
=&\exp\left({\lim_{n\to \infty}{2\log(3^n+5^n)/n}}\right)\\
=&\exp\left({\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{2\log(3)3^n+2\log(5)5^n}{3^n+5^n}}}\right)\\
=&\exp\left({\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{2\log(3)(3/5)^n+2\log(5)}{(3/5)^n+1}}}\right)\\
=&\exp\left({{\frac{[0]+2\log(5)}{[0]+1}}}\right)\\
=&\exp\left(2\log 5\right)\\
=&25\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Explanations:
1.Limit
2.$e^{\log(x)}=x$
3. $\lim a^{f(x)}=a^{\lim f(x)}$
4. L'Hopital
5. Divide by $5^N$
6. Evaluate the limit
7. Simplify
8. Simplify

Answer (score 4):

You may just write, as $n$ tends to $+\infty$,

$$
\begin{align}
(3^n+5^n)^{2/n}&=e^{\frac2n\log \left(3^n+5^n \right)}\\\\
&=e^{\frac2n\log \left(5^n\right)+ \frac2n\log \left(1+(3/5)^n \right)}\\\\
&=e^{2\log 5+ \frac2n \log \left(1+(3/5)^n \right)}\\\\
&=e^{2\log 5+ \frac2n (3/5)^n }\\\\
&\sim e^{2\log 5}\times e^0\\\\
&\sim25
\end{align}
$$ where we have used 
$$
\log (1+x)\sim_0 x
$$ with $x:=(3/5)^n$, $n$ being great.

Comment: Question: why can he write as $n$ tends to $+\infty$? Why can we disregard $-\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty }\sqrt[n]{(3^n+5^n)^2}=\\\lim_{n \to \infty }\sqrt[n]{(5^n((\frac{3}{5})^n+1))^2}=\\5^2\lim_{n \to \infty }\sqrt[n]{((\frac{3}{5})^n+1)^2}=\\$$as we now $$\lim_{n \to \infty }(\frac{3}{5})^n=0$$so $$5^2\lim_{n \to \infty }\sqrt[n]{((\frac{3}{5})^n+1)^2}=5^2*\sqrt[n]{(0+1)^2}=25$$

Comment: This assumes without proof that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(n)^{1/n} = 1$ whenever $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(n) = 1$ (true, but this is a significant step).